# How to provide functionality to search groupchat with quickblox

Tags: ios, search, chat, quickblox, groupchat

I want to implement a functionality in a chat app by which user will be able to search a group by its unique provided code. I have used quickblox for implementing chat functionality. so please provide me a way to do that functionality with quickblox.

Answer (score 0):

Please check official Document of Quickchat .

**[SimpleSample-chat_users-ios](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios)**

They have mention all the detail in their document.

Moreover , Just Download the demo and try to implement.

**[Group_chat](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/Group_chat)**

Before implement Group chat don't forget to read typical setting section.

> Typical settings [Functionality in Groupchat]
>
> Authentication: Chat history: you may wish to keep
>   the archive of all public discussion history which is easily supported
>   by QuickBlox. Some platforms will also require you to implement abuse
>   and moderation mechanisms which are also supported both via API and
>   admin panel. File attachments: typically attachments are not supported
>   1:1 / IM chat: in many applications you may wish to allow users start
>   a private communication with other user Friending: QuickBlox supports
>   friending or adding other users to favourites which you may use in
>   your application - see also [chat: friending / favourite users lists]

start groupchat with creating Dialogue.

**[Create_new_group_chat_dialog](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Create_new_group_chat_dialog)**

> QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc]
>   initWithDialogID:null type:QBChatDialogTypeGroup];
>       chatDialog.name = @"Chat with Bob, Sam, Garry"; //set according to requirement
>       chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(55), @(678), @(22)];
>
> ```
> [QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog) {
>
> } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
>
> }];
> ```

Second step --> Create chatnotification

> ```
> - (QBChatMessage *)createChatNotificationForGroupChatCreation:(QBDialog *)dialog
> {
>     // create message:
>     QBChatMessage *inviteMessage = [QBChatMessage message];
>
>     NSMutableDictionary *customParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
>     customParams[@"xmpp_room_jid"] = dialog.roomJID;
>     customParams[@"name"] = dialog.name;
>     customParams[@"_id"] = dialog.ID;
>     customParams[@"type"] = @(dialog.type);
>     customParams[@"occupants_ids"] = [dialog.occupantIDs componentsJoinedByString:@","];
>
>     // Add notification_type=1 to extra params when you created a group chat 
>     //
>     customParams[@"notification_type"] = @"1";
>
>     inviteMessage.customParameters = customParams;
>
>     return inviteMessage;
> }
>
> ...
>
> for (NSString *occupantID in dialog.occupantIDs) {
>
>     QBChatMessage *inviteMessage = [self createChatNotificationForGroupChatCreation:dialog];
>
>     NSTimeInterval timestamp = (unsigned long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
>     customParams[@"date_sent"] = @(timestamp);
>
>     // send notification
>     //
>     inviteMessage.recipientID = [occupantID integerValue];
>
>     [[QBChat instance] sendSystemMessage:inviteMessage completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
>
>     }];
> }
> ```

You will receive opponent in this delegate .

> ```
> - (void)chatDidReceiveSystemMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message
> {
> }
> ```

You can implement required functionality in group-chat with abolve link.
  Like , **Get online users** ,**Leave group chat dialog** , **Attachment in group**. etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy, but could you please help me with how could I add custom parameters to a groupchat dialog and search that particular group by that custom parameter. Please note that I want to add acustom parameter for a groupchat dialog,and not to the user or message.